# Integer vs Double multiplication gives very strange output

Tags: java, groovy

When I am trying to multiply 3 (Integer type) with 112.1 (Double) then the result I get contains many decimal points.

```
Integer a=3;
Double b=112.1;
 Double result=a*b = 336.29999999999995
```

But when we multiply 2 (Integer) with 112.1 (Double) then decimal point is so minimal.

```
Integer a=2;
Double b=112.1;
Double result=a*b = 224.2
```

Can anybody give me the reason why this strange behavior comes?

Comment: Because `double` is stored in base 2, not base 10.

Comment: [SMBC - Secret Robot Internet](http://www.smbc-comics.com/?id=2999).

Comment: haha @ElliottFrisch

Comment: find answer here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Answer (score 0):

**You can't store actual decimal representation of fractions.**

This is because computer use binary to save any value, including fractional values.

Therefore, there is some difference between actually saved one and what you want to store.